# Is ServerManager module available on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, powershell

Is ServerManager module available on **Windows 7 Ultimate** ?

I think (but I'm not sure because I never looked at output before) the PS script that I have worked before but after some problems with IIS7 installation it stopped working.

Following script

```
import-module servermanager
```

fails with error

```
Import-Module : The specified module 'servermanager' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory.
At line:1 char:14
+ import-module <<<<  servermanager
    + CategoryInfo          : ResourceUnavailable: (servermanager:String) [Import-Module], FileNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Modules_ModuleNotFound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ImportModuleCommand
```

I found recommendation to run

```
Dism.exe /Online /Enable-Feature /FeatureName:ServerManager-PSH-Cmdlets
```

on my machine but it also fails with error `Feature name ServerManager-PSH-Cmdlets is unknown.`

Comment: Did you have [this](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=7887) installed when you tried to run that script?

Comment: What is "this" ?

Comment: Look at the link, and see.  BTW It appears that @music2myear added an answer with the same link.

Comment: Ah ok. Yes, his answer doesn't work unfortunately.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

To run Server Manager on Windows 7 you need to download and install the Remote Server Management toolkit from MS

Info link: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd759202.aspx

Download link: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=7887

**UPDATE: new OP info**

The problem is that Windows 7 is not a server OS and Server Manager is not designed to manage or monitor non-server OSes. You can install Server Manager on a Windows 7 computer, but only for the purpose of managing *other* server systems. While there may be a hack to get it to work in the way you want, I'm not aware of what that hack may be.

So I guess the next question is: Why?

If you're just trying to see what you can do with Power Shell: This fix will probably take more than just PS to hack together.

IF you're trying to actually manage a Windows 7 computer in a server role: The answer's probably the same as above: If you can hack it, great. Otherwise, sorry.

Comment: Shall I install x64 only (which matches my system) or both ?

Comment: the 64 bit should be able to manage the lower system I suppose.

Comment: Is the server 32bit?

Comment: I don't have server. It's Windows 7 x64. I just installed x64 version of Remote Server Management toolkit and so far it didn't help. I'll reboot my machine now to see if it changes anything.

Comment: So you're trying to run Windows 7 as a server and have the Server Manager tool to manage it?

Comment: I'm trying to make `import-module servermanager` command in PowerShell work and curious if it's even possible on Windows 7.

Comment: Okay, Remote Server Management Toolkit didn't help. PS still can't find ServerManager module. Any other ideas, guys ?

Answer (score 2):

Since incorrect answer surprisingly continues to gain upvotes I feel obligated to post my own.

Unfortunately the solution suggested by @music2myear doesn't work.

The workaround for Windows 7 is to use 3rd party script called [PSClientManager](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/PSClientManager).

The only gotcha with it is that it's unsigned therefore PowerShell refused to use it. You can disable signature by of the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4037939/powershell-execution-of-scripts-is-disabled-on-this-system).

Answer (score 2):

The ability to use your Win7 Pro laptop to mange Windows servers is the expectation here--and a reasonable one at that. Some shops frown on admins logging into servers for every little admin function (what roles, features, patch level etc.). What about the guy who's doing QA on servers about to deploy to a remote location? He needs to log in to each box (that's stupid)? Installing RSAT on your Win7 client means you should be able to use PowerShell mods (Servermanager) to do BASIC administration, QA, Audit, etc.